# sign in with google api java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

iam using openid  to sign in with google api and i was able to redirect the website through openid  by accessing google (authentication) but i was unable to access  user infoemation i.e i nedd  user email id  to save into my database  and  here is my openid servlet code :

```
public class OpenIdServlet extends HttpServlet {

    static final long ONE_HOUR = 3600000L;
    static final long TWO_HOUR = ONE_HOUR * 2L;
    static final String ATTR_MAC = "openid_mac";
    static final String ATTR_ALIAS = "openid_alias";
    String email_id=null;
    String first_name=null;
    String last_name=null;

    private OpenIdManager manager;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        manager = new OpenIdManager();
        manager.setRealm("http://aws.lifeboard.in:8080");
        manager.setReturnTo("http://aws.lifeboard.in:8080/#!home");
    }

    public void login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,String Google)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String op="Google";
         manager = new OpenIdManager();
         manager.setRealm("http://aws.lifeboard.in:8080/");
         manager.setReturnTo("http://aws.lifeboard.in:8080/#!home");
         if (op==null) {
            // check sign on result from Google or Yahoo:
            checkNonce(request.getParameter("openid.response_nonce"));
            // get authentication:
            byte[] mac_key = (byte[]) request.getSession().getAttribute(ATTR_MAC);
            String alias = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(ATTR_ALIAS);
            Authentication authentication = manager.getAuthentication(request, mac_key, alias);
            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            showAuthentication(authentication);
            return;
        }
        if (op.equals("Google") || op.equals("Yahoo")) {
            // redirect to Google or Yahoo sign on page:
            System.out.println("enterutrerrereererererer");
            Endpoint endpoint = manager.lookupEndpoint(op);

            System.out.println("endpoint"+endpoint);
            Association association = manager.lookupAssociation(endpoint);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ATTR_MAC, association.getRawMacKey());
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ATTR_ALIAS, endpoint.getAlias());
            String url = manager.getAuthenticationUrl(endpoint, association);
            AuthenticationControllerDb authenticationControllerDb=new AuthenticationControllerDb();
            String alias = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(ATTR_ALIAS);
            System.out.println("=========================Url"+url);

            response.sendRedirect(url);
            // Create a state token to prevent request forgery.
            // Store it in the session for later validation.
            String state = new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("state", state);
            // Read index.html into memory, and set the client ID,
            // token state, and application name in the HTML before serving it.
            return new Scanner(new File("index.html"), "UTF-8")
                .useDelimiter("\\A").next()
                .replaceAll("[{]{2}\\s*CLIENT_ID\\s*[}]{2}", CLIENT_ID)
                .replaceAll("[{]{2}\\s*STATE\\s*[}]{2}", state)
                .replaceAll("[{]{2}\\s*APPLICATION_NAME\\s*[}]{2}",
                            APPLICATION_NAME);



            // get authentication:
        }
        else {
            throw new ServletException("Unsupported OP: " + op);
        }
    }



    void showAuthentication( Authentication auth) {
        //pw.print("<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /><title>Test JOpenID</title></head><body><h1>You have successfully signed on!</h1>");
      //  pw.print("<p>Identity: " + auth.getIdentity() + "</p>");
      //  pw.print("<p>Email: " + auth.getEmail() + "</p>");
    //    pw.print("<p>Full name: " + auth.getFullname() + "</p>");
        AuthenticationControllerDb authenticationControllerDb=new AuthenticationControllerDb();
        email_id=auth.getEmail();
        first_name=auth.getFirstname();
        last_name=auth.getLastname();
        Map<String,Object> registration=authenticationControllerDb.googleRegistration(email_id,first_name,last_name);
     //   pw.print("<p>First name: " + auth.getFirstname() + "</p>");
      //  pw.print("<p>Last name: " + auth.getLastname() + "</p>");
    //    pw.print("<p>Gender: " + auth.getGender() + "</p>");
     //   pw.print("<p>Language: " + auth.getLanguage() + "</p>");
      //  pw.print("</body></html>");
      //  pw.flush();
    }

    void checkNonce(String nonce) {
        // check response_nonce to prevent replay-attack:
        if (nonce==null || nonce.length()<20)
            throw new OpenIdException("Verify failed.");
        // make sure the time of server is correct:
        long nonceTime = getNonceTime(nonce);
        long diff = Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() - nonceTime);
        if (diff > ONE_HOUR)
            throw new OpenIdException("Bad nonce time.");
        if (isNonceExist(nonce))
            throw new OpenIdException("Verify nonce failed.");
        storeNonce(nonce, nonceTime + TWO_HOUR);
    }

    // simulate a database that store all nonce:
    private Set<String> nonceDb = new HashSet<String>();

    // check if nonce is exist in database:
    boolean isNonceExist(String nonce) {
        return nonceDb.contains(nonce);
    }

    // store nonce in database:
    void storeNonce(String nonce, long expires) {
        nonceDb.add(nonce);
    }

    long getNonceTime(String nonce) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                    .parse(nonce.substring(0, 19) + "+0000")
                    .getTime();
        }
        catch(ParseException e) {
            throw new OpenIdException("Bad nonce time.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google OpenID2 is deprecated. You should use [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) for login with Google.

Comment: Thank  you   and  now iam using oauth2   and code is   like this  this

Comment: Thanks  and  started using  OAuth 2